# iPhone : does apple provide an official iPhone image

Tags: iphone

Every marketing page for an app has one, does apple provide a sanctioned version png or jpeg? I know a google search will give me 12 million images of an iphone.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming or software development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they do. https://developer.apple.com/iphone/appstore/marketing.html You'll have to login to be able to access these resources.

Comment: Does that require paying to be an iPhone developer first?

Comment: I think you can join the program without paying but I am not entirely sure if you will have access to the marketing resources then.

Comment: @tobiasbayer link is broken, i found an alternative: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/#images

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what kind of image of an iPhone you're looking for, but Apple does have a gallery of images of the iPhone.

http://www.apple.com/iphone/gallery/